# Repetição até que a letra correta seja digitada

Tags: c++

Usando a função `switch`,

```
case 'T' :
case 'T' :

default:
```

Como é que faço para por exemplo os dois cases representam uma letra cada um, mas caso o utilizador escolha outra diferente então segue por `default` que vai voltar a refazer a mesma pergunta, (escolher uma letra entre `T` e `F`).

---

O que eu queria era por exemplo: Escolha uma letra entre `P` ou `B`, caso o utilizador escolha a Letra `C` o sistema diz que a letra está incorreta e volta a fazer a mesma pergunta.

Comment: Não entendi o que está pretendendo, pode explicar melhor?

Comment: Bem, quanto a parte do voltar e refazer, você pode tentar usar um `while`, `do-while`, separar em uma função a parte e usar um `return` ou até mesmo usar um `goto`. Mas para saber qual seria o melhor caso, você tem que explicar melhor o seu problema.

Answer (score 2):

Essa é a sintaxe básica do `switch`:

```
switch (letra)
{
    case 'T': 
        // Código;
        break;
    case 'F': 
        // Código;
        break;
    default: 
        // Código;
        break;
}
```

EDIT: Conforme seu comentário:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    char letra;
    do
    {
       cout << "Digite a letra correspondente: \n";
       cin >> letra;
    }
    while((letra !='T')&&(letra !='F')&&(letra !='t')&&(letra !='f'));

    switch (letra)
    {
        case 'T': 
        case 't': 
            cout << "Digitou a letra T.\n";
            break;
        case 'F':
        case 'f': 
            cout << "Digitou a letra F.\n";
            break;
        default: 
            // Código;
            break;
    }

    return 0;    
}
```

Veja funcionando no [C++ Shell](http://cpp.sh/2lb45).

Esse código vai repetir até que as letras `T` ou `t` ou `F` ou `f` sejam digitadas. Essa condição é feita nessa linha: `while((letra !='T')&&(letra !='F')&&(letra !='t')&&(letra !='f'));`

Comment: O que eu queria era por exemplo: Escolha uma letra entre P ou B, caso o utilizador escolha a Letra C o sistemas diz que a letra esta incorrecta e volta a fazer a mesma pergunta

Comment: @DiogoMartins, qualquer letra diferente de "T" ou "F" vai para o default. Se você quer que fique repetindo até que a letra correta seja digitada, você pode usar um while.

Comment: Entao como ficaria o codigo utilizando o while? E sim queria que fosse repetindo ate a letra correcta ser digitada

Comment: @DiogoMartins, editei a resposta

Comment: Quando eu digito a letra certa ele nao da return ao inicio, mas em vez disso fecha a janela

Comment: @DiogoMartins, quando você digitar a letra correta, nesse código ele sai do while, como não tem mais nada, o programa é encerrado. Basta você colocar no seu código o que quer que seja executado depois que for digitado a letra T ou F.

Comment: @DiogoMartins, melhorei o código para você entender melhor.

Comment: Ok muito obrigado! So mais uma questao estou a utilizar o seguinte para gerar uma letra random, mas o print nao me devolve nada: {
       int n = rand() % 26;
       char h = (char)(n + 65);
       printf("\n %c", h);
       
       }

Comment: @DiogoMartins se você tem outra dúvida, crie uma [nova pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Não adianta nada (para a comunidade) você alterar o foco da pergunta a cada 5 minutos. Não leve a mal e bem-vindo, faça um [tour] para entender melhor como funciona o Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DiogoMartins, sobre a geração de letras aleatórias, só com esse código não é possível eu te dizer com precisão o que está acontecendo.